# Accurate precision in float in C

Tags: c, logic

Given my program for the question in the image.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int N,R,A[100],B[100],i,flag=0;
    double sol;
    scanf("%d%d",&N,&R);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&B[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(R>=A[i]&&R<=A[i+1])
        {
            sol=(double)R-(R*B[i])/100;
            flag++;
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
        sol=(double)R;
    }
    printf("%.2f",sol);
}
```

This program passes three test cases. But fails in five. And shows expected output 3176.5 and the actual output is 3177.0. How to get all the cases cleared.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOYqK.png)

Comment: Note `A[i+1]` could be out of bounds on the last loop iteration, but you have not checked anything. Be rigorous, check the return value from `scanf` (what is that) and the actual input values too.

Comment: `(R*B[i])/100` is an integer calculation. One operand needs to be cast to `double`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. A[i+1] what can be done for that.. and what to check with scanf values.

Comment: Then please read the `scanf` man page to find out what its return value means.

Comment: Yeah, I have done casting as double at that place already.

Comment: Only the first term, see @dbush answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
sol=(double)R-(R*B[i])/100;
```

Each of the variables and constants in the sub-expression `(R*B[i])/100` have type `int`, so the result is also of type `int`.  The division operation is integer division which is truncating the result.  The cast you have on `R` isn't enough because the right-hand operand of the subtraction has already been evaluated as an `int`.

Change the constant `100` to `100.0`.  That will give it type `double` which will cause the division to be floating point division.

```
sol=(double)R-(R*B[i])/100.0;
```

Also, the following comparison will read past the end of the array `A` on the last iteration:

```
if(R>=A[i]&&R<=A[i+1])
```

You need to account for the case of the last item:

```
if((R>=A[i]) && ((i==N-1) || (R<=A[i+1])) )
```

Comment: Omg, It has worked and cleared all cases. Thanks alot sir, :)

Comment: @VishnuPriya Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: @dbush No need to cast to `double` (`int - double` is `double`). Also, depending on the values of `R` and `B[i]` you may get integer overflow, so maybe `(double)R*B[i]` is needed (and the cast is back :) )

Comment: Oh I get it now sir,